# Using LESS: compile minified and non-minified versions of CSS

Tags: css, compiler-construction, less

Let me start by asking if anyone knows of a compiler like simpLESS or LESS.app that will compile LESS into both a minified and non-minified versions of the CSS? Or has anyone modified  either of those programs to save both (one for production and one for development).

Working on a very large website and just now able to implement LESS, which is saving us a bunch of time, but also requires a change in workflow. I was hoping somebody that has gone through something similar will know of a possible solution.

Also, haven't looked at LESSphp... Maybe there's an opportunity there to configure it locally to compile what we want.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do pretty much what you want with [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#php_interface)

Comment: lessphp doesn't produced the minified version by default, you would have to the minification yourself as the included [lessify class](http://leafo.net/lessphp/lessify/) will only minify blocks of CSS with one line.

Answer (score 3):

SimpLESS has a flag that turns off minification by putting `//simpless:!minify` into the LESS file. You can then easily set up both minified and non-minified by chaining another LESS file. You'll want your files to look like this:

**main.min.less**

```
Body{
    color:#000;
}

/*Here goes all your LESS, imports of other LESS files etc*/
```

**main.less**

```
//simpless:!minify
@import "main.less";
```

Get simpLESS to watch both files. Any changes made will make it recompile both versions. You then get `main.css` which is not minified and `main.min.css` which is.